# Issue clipping vector file with QGIS (geoprocessing tools)

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, vector, clip

I am trying to clip wind speed data (.shp format) to Canada's provincial boundaries (also .shp format). I am using the clip feature in vector > geoprocessing tools. For some reason the function always stops about three quarters of the way through and never completes the clip. See screenshot: [image].

Has anyone experienced this before and is anyone aware of any solutions?

Thanks for your help!

Best,

Laura

Answer (score 2):

Is the wind speed data point data? I can't say what is going on in the geoprocessing, but a clip strikes me as a bit odd for point data (if that is indeed the case!). If the wind data is stored as points, maybe consider selecting by location all those data points within the provincial boundaries and then saving that selection as a new shapefile.

Comment: Yes, it is point data. The reason I am clipping with the point data is because I noticed when I clip the raster, the resulting raster file is shifted (I realized this when I overlaid the initial point data and discovered that it no longer fell at the centre of the raster pixel but rather to the top right.) As a workaround, I decided to clip the data in point form.

Comment: By the way, I am using the most recent version of QGIS - 2.2.0-9.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you had wind speed data in a raster format and then converted the cells of that raster to points?

Comment: Nope, in it it's original format it is point data.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following what you're trying to do. From your original post it seems you have a wind speed layer as point vector data and you have a Canada provinces layer as polygon vector data. You want to derive a layer from your wind data that includes only those wind speed points within your provinces layer.

What then is the raster you're referring to and why is it important to this operation?

Comment: Originally I converted the data from vector to raster, and I tried to clip the data to the provinces. However, there seems to be an issue with QGIS when clipped with raster files; the resulting raster was clipped but also shifted. As a workaround, I decided to clip the vector data (point form) to the provinces. This is where I encounter another issue--the clipping function doesn't complete and stops about 3/4 the way through. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: I think I see. I guess what I was recommending in the first place was to forget the clip altogether, select the points that lie within your province layer and save that selection as a new layer. Wouldn't that accomplish what you're trying to do with the clip operation?

Comment: It would except that I would need to select hundreds of points (there is one data point provided for every ~111 km) to select for all of Canada.

Comment: The Spatial Query plugin can do the selecting for you :-D Download the Spatial Query Plugin and have it activated. Then on your menu, navigate to Vector>Spatial Query>Spatial Query. This will bring up a dialog box. At the top it says "Select source features from". You'll set that to your wind speed points layer. Next you have "Where the feature". In the pulldown box you'll probably want to pick "Intersects". Then you have "Reference features of". Select your Province layer. Finally "And use the result to". Make sure it's set to "Create new selection". Hit apply and you should be good

Comment: Continuing from my last comment, once the plugin has made the selection, all you have to do is go to your layers pane, right-click the wind speed layer you were selecting from, navigate to "Save Selection As..." and make it so your selection is saved as a new shapefile (or whatever other vector format you might want). And I apologize if that response came off as patronizing. I'm not really sure what your level of GIS experience is so I thought it better to be thorough rather than respectfully vague!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help; I really appreciate it. It's always better to be more specific :) I have enabled the plugin and followed the steps but I get the beach ball of death! (You know that spinning beach ball on Macs that tell you the computer is thinking.) I have tried it on my Macbook Air and Mac desktop with the same result.

Comment: I don't work with Mac, but I have had the Windows7+ equivalent occur (e.g. Not Responding). It may be a faux BBoD. When I recently used the Spatial Query tool to select several thousand points, it took quite a while. What you might consider doing is selecting one of the smaller provinces like PEI or New Brunswick and running the Spatial Query to only select those wind speed points in that particular province. That might help you determine if you're having a system problem or if it's just going to take a long time to select so many points.

Comment: Hm, good thinking. I'll try it.